# TSQL - sum and Select

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

Is it possible to get the sum of a Select statement?

```
sum(Select (VPTOTALS.TIMEINSECONDS/3600) 
    from Table XXXX
    inner join Table YYYY
    on ..... = ......
    and ..... = .....) as Hours`
```

I have seen it done but I just can't get it to work for me. I am getting  syntax error `sum(Select` and `)`as Hours

Thanks

Comment: Is this inside a select that yiu have not displayed, why have you given it an alias?

Comment: tsql and MySQL??? Either you use MySQL, or you use tsql combined with MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

No.  You do the `select` of a `sum()`:

```
(Select sum(VPTOTALS.TIMEINSECONDS/3600) 
 from Table XXXX inner join
      Table YYYY
      on ..... = ...... and
         ..... = .....
) as Hours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT SUM(VPTOTALS.TIMEINSECONDS/3600) 
FROM Table XXXX
INNER JOIN Table YYYY on ..... = ......
   and ..... = .....)
```

This will automatically sum over the whole query as there are no other non-aggregate columns in your select statement.

If you wanted to include non aggregates in your query you would need a group by clause, to split it by that variable:

```
SELECT type,
       SUM(VPTOTALS.TIMEINSECONDS/3600) 
FROM Table XXXX
INNER JOIN Table YYYY on ..... = ......
       and ..... = .....)
GROUP BY type
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is intended to be a correlated subquery, then it can be

```
Select t1.Col1
, sum( select sum(somecol) from sometbl t2 where t2.fk = t1.id ) 
   as hours
From outertbl t1
Group by t1.col1
```

But that example is contrived and not efficient.